# Can not mount disc from cdrecord in sao mode

Tags: linux

I tried to burn a livecd iso with my DVD-RW, and it seems it can not burn with cdrecord command in default tao mode.

Then I switched to sao mode, it was burned.

But it seems I can not get the burned disc mounted.

```
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

And iso9660 file system type does not work.

What's the problem?

**EDIT:**

1) burn disc:

> cdrecord  -dev=1,0,0 -sao xxx.iso

2) mount:

> mount -o loop,ro -t iso9660 /dev/cdrom /mnt/disc

Comment: iso9660 should be the default anyways. Have you verified the disc has been burned properly?

Comment: Please post the command you're using to 1) burn the DVD 2) mount the DVD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not know why, when I move to **K3C**, everything is okay now.